# CSS-3 - How can I place a white space holder above two columns?

Tags: css, html, placeholder

I know how to make columns with CSS.

But Can anyone tell me how do I do like shown in the pic?
[image]

The white space span the latter two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can image is to use two elements within the element that contains the text. Then using `float:right` can seem like one. If you want to position an image, or another `div`, above you can use `position:absolute`.

here an example css:

```
div {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
}

.whitearea {
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
     .webkit {height:350px;}
}
img {position:absolute;right:0}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NRFT3/4/

In firefox the result is as excepted, but chrome breaks it. I added a hack that make the height bigger, this improve it but doesn't make it the same as firefox. Maybe there are some additional tricks that can give you the same result in both browsers.

Comment: @Jackson Tale remove `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
     .webkit {height:350px;}
}`  http://jsfiddle.net/NRFT3/5/

Comment: I found out that you place a span for the white space in the middle of the text. But for my problem, I won't be able to figure out where to put the whitespace span in the html. Actually what I am doing is to retrieve the text from an news item from google reader. and try to display the text and image in the way shown by the pic. So I don't know where to split the text so I could insert white space to.

Comment: @Jackson Tale probably with javascript you can count characters and find the nearest dot with immediate white space. Then you can append a span element. I am not sure if this will work, but give it a try